# Semi-flexible cable for control panel terminal blocks

Tags: cables

What is the proper name for the semi-flexible cable connecting the terminal blocks? I have seen people making a 90 deg angle to these wires and it    stays that way. I went out to the market but most cables are soft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about something as below, they are not wires but are called : **Insulated flexible busbars**

[image]